# Group by to specific column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have following tables `candidatedata` and `interview_data`

candidatedata column

```
candidate_id    |indent_no    |canName             |canMob
--------------------------------------------------------------
9               |MIT-301      |AMIT PANDIT SAWANT  |NULL
112             |MIT-286      |AMIT PANDIT SAWANT  |NULL
168             |214382       |Amit Srivastava     |8699405324
227             |213837       |Amit Kumar Nagar    |7508088604
409             |213468       |Amit Kumar Tripathi |NULL
679             |MIT-325      |Amit Kumar Joshi    |9900551259
774             |REQ48394     |Amit Patel          |9110898760
862             |MIT-370      |Amit Agrawal        |9986502032
1170            |MIT-388      |Amit Kumar Singh    |7717751688
1246            |MIT-392      |Amit Sahu           |9131399323
1498            |MIT-383      |Amit Kumar          |9871020318
1751            |227106-new   |Amit Singh          |9632134007
```

interview_data

```
candidate_id    |status1          |off_status    |cvstatus               |rec_name
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
674             |ReSchedule       |NULL          |NULL                   |Dipali
587             |CV fbd Pdg       |NULL          |CV Feedback Pending    |Reeta
637             |CV Reject        |NULL          |CV Reject              |Pallavi
1539            |CV Reject        |NULL          |CV Reject              |Sonam
89              |Intv Shortlist   |NULL          |NULL                   |Swathi
965             |Intv Reject      |NULL          |NULL                   |Pallavi
480             |Intv Reject      |NULL          |NULL                   |Shishal
532             |CV fbd Pdg       |joined        |CV Feedback Pending    |Reeta
977             |CV fbd Pdg       |NULL          |CV Feedback Pending    |Nalini
1593            |Intv Shortlist   |NULL          |Srilakshmi             |
1204            |CV Reject        |NULL          |CV Reject              |Sonam
```

I want following output

```
indent_no,rec_name,count(cv fbd Pdg),count(total),name of joined candidate
```

I have applied group by clause with count but facing problem when adding name of candidate who is join

This is my current query

```
   SELECT
  indent_no,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN cvstatus IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN cvstatus LIKE 'CV Feedback Pending%' THEN 1  END) CVfdbPdg,
  (CASE WHEN off_status LIKE 'Joine%' THEN cd.canName END) as Joined
FROM interview_data id
JOIN candidatedata cd  ON id.candidate_id = cd.candidate_id
GROUP BY indent_no, canName
```

Comment: *"I have applied group by clause with count but facing problem when adding name of candidate who is join"* Then show us what the SQL you have written is, and the error you're getting.

Comment: Expected output , input ?

Comment: That is there, @xXx but it's not readable. I'm going to *guess* what it's supposed to mean, but the OP putting it in a readable format would be far more preferred as we shouldn't need to guess what their data looks like.

Comment: I''ve ***guessed*** the values of the columns of your data, however, one of your rows appears to be missing a column.

Comment: No I have provided sample data

Answer (score 1):

A bit of conditional aggregation could work for this?

```
SELECT 
  candidate.indent_no, interview.rec_name
, COUNT(interview.cvstatus) AS TotalNonEmptyCvstatus
, COUNT(*) AS Total
, MAX(CASE WHEN interview.off_status = 'joined' THEN candidate.canName END) AS [name of joined candidate]
FROM candidatedata AS candidate
LEFT JOIN interview_data AS interview
  ON interview.candidate_id = candidate.candidate_id
GROUP BY 
  candidate.indent_no, interview.rec_name
ORDER BY 
  candidate.indent_no, interview.rec_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as LukStorms just you seams need to count [CV fbd Pdg] also

```
SELECT 
  candidate.indent_no, interview.rec_name
, sum(case when id.status1='CV fbd Pdg' then 1 else 0 end)  as [CV fbd Pdg]
, COUNT(*) AS Total
, MAX(CASE WHEN interview.off_status = 'joined' THEN candidate.canName END) AS [name of joined candidate]
FROM candidatedata AS candidate
LEFT JOIN interview_data AS interview
  ON interview.candidate_id = candidate.candidate_id
GROUP BY 
  candidate.indent_no, interview.rec_name
ORDER BY 
  candidate.indent_no, interview.rec_name;
```

By the way, **then adding sample data make it related**... as now none of your data has same [candidate_id]- so it is hard to work with it.
And for future - add even not working code if you have, so that community can guide

Taking into account your used code this should show something in an actual database (not in data you presented), but I have feeling in my gut you either have some business logic we don't know or your join is incorrect.

```
SELECT
  cd.indent_no,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id.cvstatus IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id.cvstatus LIKE 'CV Feedback Pending%' THEN 1  END) CVfdbPdg,
  max(CASE WHEN off_status LIKE 'Joine%' THEN cd.canName END) as Joined
FROM interview_data id
left JOIN candidatedata cd  ON id.candidate_id = cd.candidate_id
GROUP BY indent_no, canName
```

Can you share what is your purpose from this data -  like

- "Get all interviews that ended with candidates beeing 'joined', and
  count how much this candidate had entries"

or it is :

- "Get summary information on candidates that applied, and list only
  ones who are hired for the same indent_no" ?
  From your code seams like the latest is correct.

I made lots of assumptions on your data and your initial column list in request and crafted this

```
 -- case we want to list/count by rec_name 
SELECT
  cd.indent_no, 
  id.rec_name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id.cvstatus IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS Total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN id.cvstatus LIKE 'CV Feedback Pending%' THEN 1  END) CVfdbPdg,
  max(CASE WHEN off_status LIKE 'Joine%' THEN cd.canName END) as Joined
FROM interview_data id
inner JOIN candidatedata cd  ON id.candidate_id = cd.candidate_id
GROUP BY indent_no, rec_name
order by Joined desc,cd.indent_no,id.rec_name
```

Fiddle is here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/810e4/7/0

Comment: My code id as follows.                 select indent_no,count(case when cvstatus is not null then 1 end) as Total,
count(case when cvstatus like 'CV Feedback Pending%' then 1 end) CVfdbPdg
(case when off_status like 'Joine%' then cd.canName
end) 'Joined'
from interview_data id join candidatedata cd on
id.candidate_id=cd.candidate_id
group by indent_no,canName